# Xcode 8 does not run GameScene.swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

Upon opening a new Xcode macOS Game template, the programme will only execute the GameScene.sks file and not the GameScene.swift file that controls the mouse behaviour.  I am running the exact template code Apple provides.  Why is this happening?  Is this a bug in Xcode 8.2.1?

Comment: did you check the console at the bottom of the screen? when it was acting funny for me, it provided an explanation there.

Comment: It did not say anything unusual.  I created a new Project and now it is working fine.  However the project corresponding with this error is still not recognising the GameScene.swift file.

Comment: Is it connected in your storyboard...?